# mkoctfile can't find include c++ library header file

Tags: c++, octave

I'm working with Octave in Ubuntu environment. The cpp file I want to compile to oct file use some IT++ library functions. The IT++ package is installed under /usr/local/include and /usr/local/lib. The cpp file includes header file like:

```
#include<octave.h>
#include<itpp/itcomm.h>
```

When I use mkoctfile to compile the cpp file like: "mkoctfile example.cpp -I/usr/local/include -L/usr/local/lib -litpp". It outputs error message like "can't find include file itcomm.h".

Can anyone advise me how to solve this problem? Thanks a lot!

Comment: The proper way to install itpp: `apt install libitpp-dev` See https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&keywords=itpp

Comment: Do you have a file `/usr/local/include/itpp/itcomm.h`?

Comment: Yes. The itcomm.h is inside /usr/local/include/itpp folder.

Comment: That makes no sense then. Are permission set so you can read the file? Otherwise, please copy-paste the full error message.

Comment: Try the verbose option: "mkoctfile -verbose example.cpp -I/usr/local/include -L/usr/local/lib -litpp" to display the commands it is executing and verify that the -I/usr/local/include is making its way into compile command. The actual exact error message would be helpful.